# Stage-Whisper is not working because of missing files

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg, homebrew, openai-whisper

I tried to install this here: https://github.com/Stage-Whisper/Stage-Whisper

Once i put the audio file in it, it is still loading and loading but not transcribing it.

So after that i checked the requirements and packages, if there is something missing and there is. I installed those here :

```
Node (required for Electron)
Yarn (required for Electron)
Python 3.x (required for backend)
Rust (required for backend)
ffmpeg (required for backend)
Poetry (required for backend)
```

I installed them with homebrew. There are some errors showing up, once i launch the electron programm with "yarn dev":  ERROR: "could not locate binding files"

I also tried "poetry run python stagewhisper --input /path/to/audio/file.mp3", but got following message. **Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in /Users/Administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper or its parents.**

Where do i have to put the file **pyproject.toml** and what do i have to write in it?

So i checked with brew info all tools which i need for Stage-Whisper. Screenshots:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux3B8.png)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXdAw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sirb3.png)

What i tried was to update those packages/requirements which where missing, with "sudo port install **requirementPackageName** ". But after checking with brew info again, those parts are still missing. So does that actually work or do i have to install those missing stuff with homebrew? I have Mac Mojave 10.14.6 and Homebrew 4.1.18 Version.

I also got an error, while i installed those tools with homebrew:

**ERROR**: You are using macOS 10.14.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version. It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version... etc

Thank you for your help guys.

Edit:

> yarn install v1.22.19 warning ../../../package.json: No license field
> [1/4]   Resolving packages... [2/4]   Fetching packages... [3/4]
>   Linking dependencies... warning "@emotion/react >
> @emotion/babel-plugin@11.10.2" has unmet peer dependency
> "@babel/core@^7.0.0". warning "@emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin
>
> > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.18.6" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0". warning " > autoprefixer@10.4.4" has unmet
> > peer dependency "postcss@^8.1.0". warning " >
> > eslint-config-airbnb@19.0.4" has unmet peer dependency
> > "eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4.3.0".
> > [----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/890^[4/4]   Building fresh packages... [1/7] ⠁ better-sqlite3
> > [-/7] ⠁ waiting... [3/7] ⠁ sqlite3 [4/7] ⠁ esbuild error
> > /Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3:
> > Command failed. Exit code: 1 Command: prebuild-install || npm run
> > build-release Arguments:  Directory:
> > /Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3
> > Output: prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found
> > (target=20.9.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)
>
> > better-sqlite3@7.6.2 build-release
> > node-gyp rebuild --release
>
> gyp info it worked if it ends with ok gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.0
> gyp info using node@20.9.0 | darwin | x64 gyp info find Python using
> Python version 3.9.14 found at "/usr/local/bin/python3" gyp info spawn
> /usr/local/bin/python3 gyp info spawn args [ gyp info spawn args
> '/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/electron-rebuild/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
> gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp', gyp info spawn args   '-f', gyp
> info spawn args   'make', gyp info spawn args   '-I', gyp info spawn
> args
> '/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
> gyp info spawn args   '-I', gyp info spawn args
> '/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/electron-rebuild/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
> gyp info spawn args   '-I', gyp info spawn args
> '/Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/common.gypi',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library', gyp info spawn args
> '-Dvisibility=default', gyp info spawn args
> '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0',
> gyp info spawn args
> '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/electron-rebuild/node_modules/node-gyp',
> gyp info spawn args
> '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
> gyp info spawn args
> '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3',
> gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8', gyp info spawn args
> '--depth=.', gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel', gyp info spawn
> args   '--generator-output', gyp info spawn args   'build', gyp info
> spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' gyp info spawn args ] gyp info spawn
> make gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
> TOUCH ba23eeee118cd63e16015df367567cb043fed872.intermediate   ACTION
> deps_sqlite3_gyp_locate_sqlite3_target_copy_builtin_sqlite3
> ba23eeee118cd63e16015df367567cb043fed872.intermediate   TOUCH
> Release/obj.target/deps/locate_sqlite3.stamp   CC(target)
> Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite3/sqlite3.o   LIBTOOL-STATIC
> Release/sqlite3.a   CXX(target)
> Release/obj.target/better_sqlite3/src/better_sqlite3.o In file
> included from ../src/better_sqlite3.cpp:4: In file included from
> ./src/better_sqlite3.lzz:11: In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/node.h:73:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8.h:24:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:12:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-local-handle.h:12:
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:465:30:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> SHARED_EXTERNAL_POINTER_TAGS(CHECK_SHARED_EXTERNAL_POINTER_TAGS)
> ^ /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:465:30:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:465:30:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:465:30:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:465:30:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> PER_ISOLATE_EXTERNAL_POINTER_TAGS(CHECK_NON_SHARED_EXTERNAL_POINTER_TAGS)
> ^ /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:466:35:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:693:61:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> static_assert(kJSObjectType + 1 == kFirstJSApiObjectType);
> ^
> , "" /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:694:55:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> static_assert(kJSObjectType < kLastJSApiObjectType);
> ^
> , "" /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:695:63:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> static_assert(kFirstJSApiObjectType < kLastJSApiObjectType);
> ^
> , "" In file included from ../src/better_sqlite3.cpp:4: In file included from
> ./src/better_sqlite3.lzz:11: In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/node.h:73:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8.h:24:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-object.h:9:
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-maybe.h:106:45:
> error: no template named 'is_lvalue_reference_v' in namespace 'std';
> did you mean 'is_lvalue_reference'?   template <class U,
> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_lvalue_reference_v>*>
> ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> is_lvalue_reference /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:780:50:
> note: 'is_lvalue_reference' declared here template  struct
> _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_lvalue_reference       : public false_type {};
> ^ In file included from ../src/better_sqlite3.cpp:4: In file included from
> ./src/better_sqlite3.lzz:11: In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/node.h:73:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8.h:24:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-object.h:9:
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-maybe.h:106:69:
> error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
>
> template <class U, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_lvalue_reference_v>*>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-maybe.h:123:43:
> error: no template named 'is_lvalue_reference_v' in namespace 'std';
> did you mean 'is_lvalue_reference'? template <class T,
> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_lvalue_reference_v>* = nullptr>
> ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> is_lvalue_reference /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:780:50:
> note: 'is_lvalue_reference' declared here template  struct
> _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_lvalue_reference       : public false_type {};
> ^ In file included from ../src/better_sqlite3.cpp:4: In file included from
> ./src/better_sqlite3.lzz:11: In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/node.h:73:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8.h:24:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:13:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-object.h:9:
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-maybe.h:123:67:
> error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
> template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_lvalue_reference_v>* =
> nullptr>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ In file included from ../src/better_sqlite3.cpp:4: In file included from
> ./src/better_sqlite3.lzz:11: In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/node.h:73:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8.h:33:
> In file included from
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-function.h:11:
> /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-function-callback.h:151:66:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> kReturnValueDefaultValueIndex - kReturnValueIndex);
> ^
> , "" /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.9.0/include/node/v8-function-callback.h:153:50:
> warning: static_assert with no message is a C++17 extension
> [-Wc++17-extensions]
> kIsolateIndex - kReturnValueIndex);
> ^
> , "" ./src/util/macros.lzz:157:21: error: no member named
> 'AccessorSignature' in namespace 'v8'
> v8::AccessorSignature::New(isolate, recv)
> ~~~~^ ./src/util/binder.lzz:37:51: error: no member named 'CreationContext' in 'v8::Object'
> v8::Local<v8::Context> ctx = obj->CreationContext();
> ~~~  ^ 22 warnings and 6 errors generated. make: ***
> [Release/obj.target/better_sqlite3/src/better_sqlite3.o] Error 1 rm
> ba23eeee118cd63e16015df367567cb043fed872.intermediate gyp ERR! build
> error  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR!
> stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
> (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/electron-rebuild/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28) gyp ERR!
> stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (node:internal/child_process:294:12) gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0 gyp
> ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node"
> "/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp"
> "rebuild" "--release" gyp ERR! cwd
> /Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3

**Same goes for the the "poetry install" command in the backend folder:**

8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/build/onig_sys-3a9a2f947b5ad744/out`warning: variable does not need to be mutable --> tokenizers-lib/src/models/unigram/model.rs:265:21 | 265 |                 let mut target_node = &mut best_path_ends_at[key_pos]; |                     ----^^^^^^^^^^^ |                     | |                     help: remove this`mut`| = note:`#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
--> tokenizers-lib/src/models/unigram/model.rs:282:21
|
282 |                 let mut target_node = &mut best_path_ends_at[starts_at + mblen];
|                     ----^^^^^^^^^^^
|                     |
|                     help: remove this `mut`

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
--> tokenizers-lib/src/pre_tokenizers/byte_level.rs:200:59
|
200 |     encoding.process_tokens_with_offsets_mut(|(i, (token, mut offsets))| {
|                                                           ----^^^^^^^
|                                                           |
|                                                           help: remove this `mut`

error: casting `&T` to `&mut T` is undefined behavior, even if the reference is unused, consider instead using an `UnsafeCell`
--> tokenizers-lib/src/models/bpe/trainer.rs:526:47
|
522 |                     let w = &words[*i] as *const _ as *mut _;
|                             -------------------------------- casting happend here
...
526 |                         let word: &mut Word = &mut (*w);
|                                               ^^^^^^^^^
|
= note: `#[deny(invalid_reference_casting)]` on by default

warning: `tokenizers` (lib) generated 3 warnings
error: could not compile `tokenizers` (lib) due to previous error; 3 warnings emitted

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/administrator/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/rustc --crate-name tokenizers --edition=2018 tokenizers-lib/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="cached-path"' --cfg 'feature="clap"' --cfg 'feature="cli"' --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="http"' --cfg 'feature="indicatif"' --cfg 'feature="progressbar"' --cfg 'feature="reqwest"' -C metadata=cb36f9861d265e60 -C extra-filename=-cb36f9861d265e60 --out-dir /private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps -L dependency=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps --extern aho_corasick=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libaho_corasick-021885281f13d108.rmeta --extern cached_path=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libcached_path-767095c4d4a77107.rmeta --extern clap=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libclap-c92d2593d8a75e62.rmeta --extern derive_builder=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libderive_builder-833217c2af636976.dylib --extern dirs=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libdirs-f12e99ecd3a76eae.rmeta --extern esaxx_rs=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libesaxx_rs-b694f04df571686b.rmeta --extern indicatif=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libindicatif-39491a3282a24810.rmeta --extern itertools=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libitertools-b322e49e83853c17.rmeta --extern lazy_static=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/liblazy_static-28a96417d88df3c9.rmeta --extern log=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/liblog-937f94f366843d8a.rmeta --extern macro_rules_attribute=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libmacro_rules_attribute-d4d77bee9330e675.rmeta --extern onig=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libonig-7f9dab4334743bdf.rmeta --extern paste=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libpaste-a36a4a0dbc2ac63f.dylib --extern rand=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/librand-4b1adc86e35ea892.rmeta --extern rayon=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/librayon-d134e48f83d52e6e.rmeta --extern rayon_cond=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/librayon_cond-5715a923c66c54a9.rmeta --extern regex=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libregex-a5c54f2d0034ab98.rmeta --extern regex_syntax=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libregex_syntax-58c405f62323b6ed.rmeta --extern reqwest=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libreqwest-1551c89d20e17f58.rmeta --extern serde=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libserde-f4748cc953dd1338.rmeta --extern serde_json=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libserde_json-5fba404e8440399e.rmeta --extern spm_precompiled=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libspm_precompiled-6bd24072bd3c9d31.rmeta --extern thiserror=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libthiserror-bcbb2769006ee534.rmeta --extern unicode_normalization_alignments=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libunicode_normalization_alignments-658520cf6a5461dc.rmeta --extern unicode_segmentation=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libunicode_segmentation-fffd829ab6256bb0.rmeta --extern unicode_categories=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/deps/libunicode_categories-e3815c3d18c1086b.rmeta -L native=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/build/bzip2-sys-d2cb72d65b178690/out/lib -L native=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/build/zstd-sys-ddff0154a55a136c/out -L native=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/build/esaxx-rs-69d9e34a40d41449/out -L native=/private/var/folders/zc/c2qvlcjd5cgcg5l84484t8vh0000gt/T/tmp2yohvwu_/tokenizers-0.12.1/target/release/build/onig_sys-3a9a2f947b5ad744/out` (exit status: 1)
error: `cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path Cargo.toml --release -v --features pyo3/extension-module --crate-type cdylib -- -C 'link-args=-undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-install_name,@rpath/tokenizers.cpython-311-darwin.so'` failed with code 101

at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/installation/chef.py:166 in _prepare
162│
163│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
164│
165│             if error is not None:
→ 166│                 raise error from None
167│
168│             return path
169│
170│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with tokenizers (0.12.1) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "tokenizers (==0.12.1)"'.

UPDATE (SOLVED):

- i found a solution and this worked for me :

"I had the same problem and nothing mentioned here worked for me. Here is what worked for me:

```
**("Didnt do this Part")"Require all dependencies you need in the main.js file that is run by electron."**
```

What i did was :
Run npm i -D electron-rebuild to add the electron-rebuild package
Remove the node-modules folder, as well as the packages-lock.json file.
Run npm i to install all modules.
Run ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild (.\node_modules.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd for Windows) to rebuild everything

It is very important to run ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild directly after npm i otherwise it did not work on my mac."

But now i get following Error, when i upload and transcribe the file:

```
> [ELECTRON] NewEntry: Creating new entry with UUID: XY...
[ELECTRON] NewEntry: Copying audio file to store...
[ELECTRON] NewEntry: Audio file copied to store.
[ELECTRON] NewEntry: Entry added to database!
[ELECTRON] RunWhisper: Running model with args [
[ELECTRON]   '--verbose',
[ELECTRON]   'true',
[ELECTRON]   '--output_dir',
[ELECTRON]   '/Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/stagewhisper/store/whisper/2a07203b-ad88-438c-babf-b600cb76aa1d',
[ELECTRON]   '--task',
[ELECTRON]   'translate',
[ELECTRON]   '--model',
[ELECTRON]   'base',
[ELECTRON]   '--device',
[ELECTRON]   'cpu',
[ELECTRON]   '--input',
[ELECTRON]   '/Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/stagewhisper/store/audio/harvard.mp3'
[ELECTRON] ]
[ELECTRON] RunWhisper: Child process closed with code 1
[ELECTRON] RunWhisper: Error running whisper script!
[ELECTRON] Error occurred in handler for 'run-whisper': Error: Error running whisper script!
[ELECTRON]     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/main/handlers/runWhisper/runWhisper.js:234:31)
[ELECTRON]     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
[ELECTRON]     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
[ELECTRON]     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
[ELECTRON]     at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
[ELECTRON]     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
```

Comment: First, you need to clone the repository. Second, you need to install all **Prerequisites** dependencies successfully. Afterward, go to the cloned repository and execute the `cd backend` and `poetry install` commands as mentioned in the `README.md` file.

Comment: i did, but look down below i got some errors

Comment: where are you peter please help, it seems like nobody else is left here in this planet lol

Comment: I have managed to resolve the problems on Windows 10, see the answer below. It might be different on macOS however you can apply the same methods. I would suggest you start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install and run the backend service successfully on Windows 10 by applying the following steps:

**1. Clone the stage whisper repository**

```
git clone https://github.com/Stage-Whisper/Stage-Whisper.git
```

**2. Install all the prerequisites. Verify with the following command:**

```
node -v && yarn -v && python --version && rustup --version && ffmpeg -version && poetry --version
```

This is the version output:

```
v18.18.0 # <-- node version
1.22.21 # <-- yarn version
Python 3.11.5 # <-- self-explanatory
rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05) # <-- rust version
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.72.0 (5680fa18f 2023-08-23)`
ffmpeg version 6.1-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers # <-- ffmpeg 6.1 version
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102
libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100
libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100
libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100
libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
Poetry (version 1.5.1) # <-- self-explanatory
```

**3. (Optional) I am using the following configuration for the poetry package manager:**

```
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
poetry config virtualenvs.prefer-active-python true
```

With these settings, it will create a new `.venv` folder within the `backend` directory.

**4. Install the backend dependencies with Poetry:**

```
poetry install
```

However, I got the "Unable to find installation candidates for torch (1.12.1)" error. Therefore, I manually resolved the `torch` dependency with this command:

```
poetry add torch
```

It added the ^2.1.1 version in my case. It installs the other dependencies as well.

**5. Run the `stagewhisper` project with Poetry.**

Download a simple audio file or use an existing one. I downloaded the https://pixabay.com/sound-effects/happy-birthday-in-english-male-15023/ in which an English male sings the "Happy Birthday" song. Then, I replaced it with the `backend` folder and ran the following command:

```
poetry run python stagewhisper --input happy-birthday-in-english-male-15023.mp3
C:\Users\<path_to_the_repository>\Stage-Whisper\backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py:70: UserWarning: FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead
  warnings.warn("FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead")
Detected language: english
 Happy birthday to you
```

I got some warnings about the floating point number precision because the CPU does not support FP16 precision. In any case, the `stagewhisper` managed to transcribe the audio file.

Additionally, it created the `happy-birthday-in-english-male-15023.mp3.vtt` with the following content:

```
WEBVTT

00:00.000 --> 00:12.560
 Happy birthday to you
```